# JSONB - query Postgres

Tags: java, postgresql, jsonb

I have following table with data

```
cars.details (country_id, city_id, value)

1. ('JAP', '53', ('{"model":"Toyota", "weight":"900", "description":"Family Car.", "tires":"3"}'))


cards.additions (country_id, city_id, value)

1. ('JAP', '53', ('{"size":"1","color":"100","description":"Family Car.","additions": ["ac", "rails"]}'))
```

I need to select and join 2 tables to receive following:

return response from 2 tables where:

cars.details.country_id = cards.additions.country_id
AND
cars.details.city_id = cards.additions.city_id

following fields I am trying to return:

from cars.details:
country_id, city_id, model, weight, description

+

from cars.additions
size, color, additions

My query is not working:

```
select country_id, city_id, value -> 'model' as model, value -> 'weight' as weight, value  -> 'description' as descr from products.details inner join cars.additions on cars.additions.country_id = products.nutrition.country_id AND cars.additions.city_id = products.nutrition.city_id;
```

Please advise

Thanks

Comment: Can you update your post by having both sample input data and expected output inside tables? If you don't know how to do that, you can follow the answer of [this post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/302471/how-to-put-tables-in-stack-overflow).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Few Things :**

Why have you used `products.details` in the query when you have `cars.details` in the description ?

You have used incorrect key access in JSON column: In the query, you are using "value -> 'model'" but in the description, you are using "model". The correct key access for the JSON column should be "value -> 'model'" as in the query.

You have used incorrect field name in the result set: In the query, you are using "descr" but in the description, you are using "description". You should use the same name in the query as in the description.

Try this :

```
select cars.details.country_id, cars.details.city_id, cars.details.value -> 'model' as model, cars.details.value -> 'weight' as weight, cars.details.value -> 'description' as description, cars.additions.value -> 'size' as size, cars.additions.value -> 'color' as color, cars.additions.value -> 'additions' as additions from cars.details inner join cars.additions on cars.additions.country_id = cars.details.country_id AND cars.additions.city_id = cars.details.city_id;
```